# Iterando select dinamico em adicionar e remover linhas

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Estou desenvolvendo um adicionar e remover linhas como na imagem[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O primeiro select vem de um database com PHP e os que são adicionados posteriormente dinamicamente  vem através do getJSON. Está funcionando porém estão sendo feitas várias requisições sem parar desse getJSON e o select fica acumulando as mesmas informações, estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {

  $.ajax({
      type:'post',  
      dataType: 'json',  
      url: 'json/list_programs',
      success: function(dados){
        var programs = '';
        $.each(dados, function(key, value){
            programs += '' + value.program_name + '';
        });
        $('.list_programs').append(programs);

      }
    });

});
```

Comment: *"porém estão sendo feitas várias requisições sem parar desse getJSON"* tem duas coisas possíveis de fazer, ou mudar o evento que está disparando as requisições (DOMSubtreeModified), ou devolver sempre a lista completa de opções, e no lugar de append fazer o replace das opções

Comment: Não seria o caso de esvaziar o select antes de popular ele? `$('.list_programs').empty().append(programs);`

Comment: @RicardoPontual qual evento eu mudaria para essas requisições? Devolver uma lista completa, como assim?

Comment: @Sam se eu colocar o empty ela fica sempre vazia

Comment: Vc que popular todos os selects de uma vez com o que vem do AJAX?

Comment: @Sam eu quero popular o select de cada linha que for adicionada. Quando clicar no botão adicionar nova linha, o select referente a ela tem que ser populado via ajax. Não é todos de uma vez e sim somente o da linha que for adicionada. Dessa maneira ele funciona, so que fica fazendo várias requisições sem parar, tipo um loop e assim vai duplicando as informações no select. Tipo adicionei nova linha aí popula o select referente a ele e para a requisição.

Comment: Então teria que adicionar :last para pegar só o último e adicionar a listagem: `$('.list_programs:last').append(programs);`

Comment: @Sam funcionou so que não para de fazer requisições, um problema foi resolvido, mas o segundo não, sem interagir com a pagina ela fica buscando as informações a cada momento, sera que é por causa do evento DOMSubtreeModified?

Comment: Sim. Esse evento é disparado quando há alterações no DOM. O certo era chamar o AJAX apenas quando uma linha for adicionada.

Comment: @Sam resolvi dessa forma que disse, coloquei o ajax em uma função e chamei no evento do click da nova linha, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @Sam teria como a cada adição de linha a linha anterior ficar com o valor do select escolhido anteriormente? Porque quando eu adiciona uma linha eu chamo a função para buscar os dados para o select, mas sempre que adiciono nova linha faz outra chamada e todas as linhas anteriores voltam ao primeiro valor, devido estar chamando a função do select, teria alguma forma de fixar esse valor escolhido?

Comment: Quando vc adiciona uma linha vc popula todos os selects de todas as linhas?

Comment: @Sam populo o select da linha adicionada, so que as linhas anteriores voltam ao valor normal. Se eu adicionei 3 linhas e coloquei valores diferentes no select: carro, bicicleta, patinete aí quando adiciono  outra linha, esses 3 valores voltam para o padrão SELECIONE UM ITEM por exemplo. Queria que ficasse fixado os valores anteriores que eu escolhi. Eu sei que isso esta acontecendo porque chamo a função que popula sempre que adiciono a nova linha, mas queria saber se tem uma maneira de 'travar' os valores anteriores que foram escolhidos

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido colocando o EMPTY e chamando o ajax dentro do evento click de adicionar nova linha

`$('.list_programs').empty().append(programs);`